# Why do I always get “Returned values are not valid, did it run Out of Gas”?

Tags: truffle, transactions, blockchain, private-blockchain, out-of-gas

I'm new on Ethereum blockchain and I'm working on deploy and using smart contract using truffle on my  private blockchain.

I have followed exactly this guide 
 https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts

But every time i call *getBalance()* function

```
  truffle(develop)> let balance = await instance.getBalance(accounts[0])
  truffle(develop)> balance.toNumber()
```

I get the error: 
Returned values are not valid, did it run Out of Gas

So I added a simply smart contract *getNumber()* then return a simply integer (3) and I always get the same error.

But if I invoke *sendCoin()* function  I don't get any error and i write correctly the transaction.

So i get the error any time i try to get values from blockchain.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a view (read-only) function in `web3.js` and `ethjs` are object-like types, with string keys for the integer positions of the return values.

If you stringified it, it would look like
`{'0': BN<some balance here>}`

Try `balance['0'].toNumber()`

If your view functions return multiple values, it would look like

```
`{'0': val0, '1': val1, ... }`
```